# In Vim how to know if function is defined

Tags: vim

I am using Vim editor v7.4 .
I have a huge C Code library , and i make constant changes to it.
 
Is there a way ( before compilation) to know if a function i am adding to some  file is defined for this file.

Thanks

Comment: Other than `/functionName`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to correctly understand your need. In my definition, when I add a function to a file, I add its definition, so it's defined. But when I'm using a function in a file, I only need its declaration. Then there is also the problem of being sure that a function defined in a translation unit is declared somewhere (privately in the same TU as a static function, or in a header file).

For the latter, I have a solution (that checks functions definitions and declarations are balanced in [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp)). For the case of being sure a function is declared in the UT it's used, it won't be that simple: we need to do the preprocessor work (and recursively follow includes) and search whether a function is indeed declared. It's not impossible, but it's best to have vim know the paths where header files are in order to look for them.

Answer (score 0):

Look at a tool like **exuberant ctags**. It parses C-style files to find any identifier and store them in a tag file, so that each of them can be accessed quickly, inside Vim for example.

Once installed, in the shell command line, you have to create a tag file with this kind of command:

```
$ ctags *.c *.h
```

This will create an new file called `tags`, where all the c files and header files in the current directory are parsed. Please note that there are many options for this tool (like recursively include all lib headers, which can lead to a huge file, though), you may look at the doc for more details.

Once done, in Vim, there are several commands to use transparently the infos in this file. First check your current directory is the same as the tag file; then, to check if an identifier (like a function name) is already present in the tag file, you can use:

```
:ts myFunctionName
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think tag is a good enough solution to check whether function is defined. The flexibility of C syntax make it worse, because most tag tool is syntax-based other than semantics-based.

For example, at present, the most powerful code-completion plug-in for vim is
[YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe), which is semantic-based by virtue of [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/).

So IMHO, the answer to your question is: **compile it!**

In order to do compiling more convenience, you can add the following configuration in your .vimrc.
`map <F6> :make install<CR>`

After this, when you press F6, compiler will be launched to check your code.